# Time series object gives incorrect time frame

Tags: r, time-series

I am working on a "data.frame" object and trying to convert it to "ts" object. Below is the sample data:

```
 date   sales
 5/1/2015   200
 5/1/2015   189.83
 6/1/2015   500
 7/1/2015   400
 8/1/2015   345
 9/1/2015   2948.87
 10/1/2015  3847.39
 10/1/2015  473.45
```

10/1/2015 is not max date there is much more data.

Below is the Rcode:

```
f <- data.frame(fs$date, fs$sales )

colnames(f) <- c("date","sales")
head(f, n=5)
class(f) 

flt <- ts(f$sales, start = c(2015,1),freq = 12)
head(flt, n = 10)
str(flt)
```

For the str I am not getting the 2015 to 6694 correctly.

> Time-Series [1:56150] from 2015 to 6694: 200 189.83 500 400 354 ...

How to set to correct time frame with correct sales amount? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you`dput(fs)` and post the output in your question so we can [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) your example please.

Comment: Data is way too large, that why I posted sample few rows. I also cannot share the original data set.

Comment: Just curious, but do you need to convert it to "ts" for some operation? I've had some frustration in the past with "ts" for certain things like this.

Comment: `dput(fs[1:10,])` so we have something to play with at least.

Comment: The first two dates in your input are the same and the last two dates in your input are the same so it is not a time series.  Also as others have pointed out the code in the question is not reproducible so it's impossible to really know what you have.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I missed that, excellent point! You would need to add up each day, giving a single data point per day to generate a true time series. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I am planning on using linear regression or time series to predict the future sales values. I'll have use "ts" time series object. There are many dates that are similar, do I need to combine these or order them in chronological order? Please see the dput output:

Comment: structure(list(date = c(20150401L, 20150401L, 20150401L, 20150401L, 
                        20150501L, 20150501L, 20150401L, 20150501L, 20150601L, 20150601L
), sales = c(940, 212, 969.4, 484.7, 700, 940, 20540, 15326, 
             969.4, 290)), .Names = c("date", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                      10L), class = "data.frame")